# Charter matrix in java

Tags: java, matrix, character

I have a two dimensional character matrix, cross[][] and I want to get its value on a line x and row y. 
I've tried

```
char c1[] = cross[x];
char c2 = c1[y] ;
```

but I get an error on line 2, "array required, but char found" 
What can I do?
(I'm a newbie and English isn't my first language, sorry for any mistakes)

Comment: Please show us what is `cross, x, y.`

Comment: you probably want to use `char c = cross[x][y]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want *x* number of rows and *y* number of columns, I would use

```
Variablename == new char[x][y]
```

*x* and *y* have to be defined first.

Comment: You misunderstood what I said. I don't want to make a new matrix, I have one, cross[][], and I want to take the value of a specific cell, cross[x][y].